# New school and old school

Tags: soft-question

I heard a lot of this two way of play, but I actually don't understand in which they differs. Which are the differences between old school of poker and new school?

Comment: Hi @emanuele, I'm closing this question as it's too broad and doesn't have any definitive answer. "Old" and "New" school don't actually relate to any specific principles that differentiate them, significantly. Styles are arbitrary and as time passes, new styles dominate the current theory of poker.

Comment: ok, I am sorry.